# How to identify $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ from numerical value of $x=a+b\sqrt{5}$?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I know the numerical value of $x$, also know it can be written as $x=a+b\sqrt{c}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $c$ is known.

For example: try to find $a+b\sqrt{5}=8.70820393249937$.

[image: Answer from Wolfram Alpha]

WolframAlpha said it's $2+3\sqrt{5}$, that's right.

Comment: Subtract or add multiples of $\sqrt5$ until you get an integer?

Comment: PARI/GP has a command called "lindep", which can solve problems of this kind.

Comment: Another way is to calculate the minimal polynomial, which is $x^2-4x-41$ in this case. But I don't know an algorithm to calculate it by hand.

Comment: No exhaustive method...pls

Comment: There is no exact method, because you don't know exactly what's coming after $9937$, which opens up infinitely many possibilities for what exactly $a$ and $b$ could be.

Comment: Note that Wolfram Alpha says : "possible closed forms" The results are reasonable guesses. It is clear that we cannot prove some closed form to be the number because if the number is irrational (which is the case here), we can only write down finite many digits.

Comment: If $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt5]$ is dense in$\mathbb{R}$, then there is no best answer, without constraints.

Comment: Maybe can defind one approximation like [Diophantine Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) ?

Comment: You might be interested in "integer relation algorithms" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm